# Subtracting .size() function values of different strings

Tags: c++, string, unsigned

Recently I encountered a problem while I was trying to subtract `.size()` values of two strings in c++. As far as I know, `size()` returns number of characters in a string. So lets say I have 2 strings `p` and `q`, `abs(p.size()-q.size())` should return me difference in length of both strings. But when I ran this code, it returned an abruptly large value. When I individually print the length of both or if I store their length values in different integers and subtract them, they give me correct answer. Am not yet able to figure out why.

Comment: `.size()` returns `size_t` that is an unsigned integer, thus you get an overflow.

Comment: Btw., size returns the number of *bytes* which may be not the same as the number of characters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`size()` returns an unsigned value. A smaller unsigned value minus a larger one is then underflowing the calculation, resulting in a large negative value. Think of it as if you have the "rolling" counter of miles or km in a car, and you roll back past 0, it becomes 99999, which is a big number.

The solution, assuming you care about negative differences is to do `static_cast<int>(p.size() - q.size())` (and pass that to `abs`).

Comment: On 64 bit systems, `int` may be a lot smaller than `size_t`. If you know your strings could exceed 2GB, use `long long`.

Comment: @MSalters: Yes, a common problem we see all the time here... ;)

Answer (score 4):

Return Value of size() is the number of size_t (an **unsigned integral type**) 
So if you subtract greater number from smaller number, you'll get into problem and get that big value as a result of subtraction.

Reference [std::string::size](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/size/)

Comment: A common pattern is `std::max(p.size(),q.size())-std::min(p.size(),q.size())`.

Answer (score 2):

`std::string` member function `size()` returns an unsigned value, so if `p.size() < q.size()`, the expression `p.size()-q.size()` will not evaluate to a negative number (it's unsigned, cannot be negative) but to a (often) very very big (unsigned) number.

Answer (score 2):

`std::string`s reports their size as some width of `unsigned` integer; such types are a bit like the second hand on a watch: you can wind it forward from 0 up to 59  but if you keep going clockwise it drops to 0 before incrementing again, while if you wind counterclockwise you count down to 0 then jump to 59 and count down from there, ad infinitum.

Say you are subtracting a string length of 6 from a string length of 4, it's much like saying "start the minute hand at 4 and wind counterclockwise by 6 minutes" - when you've wound back 4 minutes the second hand's already at 0, and you wind another minute to get to 59, and the final minute brings you to 58.  For `std::string::size_type` the maximum isn't 59 - it's much larger - but the problem's the same.  The result is always positive so is unaffected by `abs`, but regardless - not what you wanted!

The actual maximum value can be accessed after `#include <limits>` with `std::numeric_limits<std::string::size_type>::max()`, for whatever that's worth.

There are many ways to solve this problem.  David Schwartz's comment on Zola's answer lists one good one: `std::max(p.size(),q.size())-std::min(p.size(),q.size())`, which you can think of as *"subtract the smaller value from the larger value"*.  Another option is...

```
p.size() > q.size() ? p.size() - q.size() : q.size() - p.size()
```

...which means *"if p's larger, subtract q from it, otherwise subtract it (i.e. p) from q"*.